# Update data type with case statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update a data type in the table I work with. It currently is stored as an `int` but it really is a `date` column.

It looks like `20191012` right now. For some reason instead of using `null`, they had columns with no dates be `0`.

When I query the table I use

```
case 
   when bthdat = 0 
      then '9999-12-31' 
      else convert(date, convert(varchar(10), bthdat)) as dob
end
```

Can I use the same logic to update the actual table itself? If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: `CASE` **expression**. `Case` (`Switch`) statements don't exist in SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to `UPDATE` your existing column, as `int` and `date` aren't compatible.

What you *can* do, however, is change the datatype a couple of times, with an `UPDATE` in the middle. This, however, *assumes* that all the values are valid (for example don't have a value like `20190229`) and in the ISO format `yyyyMMdd`

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN bthdat varchar(10);

UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET bthdat = NULL
WHERE bthdat = '0';

ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ALTER COLUMN bthdat date;
```

Comment: What if there is a bad date or character? Can I use try_convert or how can I remove the poor data?

Comment: You'll need to find, and fix the bad data first, @sm86 , before the final `ALTER`. This is why using the wrong datatype is *always* the wrong decision.

Comment: You could change the `WHERE` to `WHERE bthdat = '0' OR TRY_CONVERT(date,bthdat) IS NULL` but that would, of course, cause you to lose any and all bad data with no recovery. You might be better off putting the bad data into a new column, to later review.

Comment: Thank you. I wish the datatype could be changed but I have no say.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as follows

```
update
 a
set
 bthdat = case
                    when bthdat = 0 then '9999-12-31'
                    else convert(date,convert(varchar(10),bthdat))
                end
from
   YourTable as a
```

Do not forget to set the else for records that are not updated to keep the existing value.

Comment: `'9999-12-31'` osn't a valid `int`, so this will fail.